# Sorting of an Array within with Date which comes in String Formate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, date

I want to sort the data inside array with date. I got date inside array index with key "start_date" which is in string format 
I have Array of following data:

```
    [
        {
         city = Ahmedabad;
        "start_date" = "2018-12-14";
        "start_time" = "09:00:00";
    },
        {
        city = Ahmedabad;
        "start_date" = "2018-12-13";
        "start_time" = "09:00:00";
    },
        {
         city = Ahmedabad;
        "start_date" = "2018-10-05";
        "start_time" = "09:00:00";
    },
        {
        city = Ahmedabad;
        "start_date" = "2018-10-03";
        "start_time" = "09:00:00";
    },
        {
        city = Ahmedabad;
        "start_date" = "2018-10-01";
        "start_time" = "09:00:00";
    },
        {
        city = Ahmedabad;
        "start_date" = "2018-09-04";
        "start_time" = "09:00:00";
    },
        {
        city = "Subang Jaya";
        "start_date" = "2018-10-15";
        "start_time" = "09:00:00";
    },
        {
        city = Kuching;
        "start_date" = "2018-08-22";
        "start_time" = "10:00:00";
    }
]
```

I want to sort with ascending order of date inside array by using key "start_date" which provides string of start date. Please Provide me suggestions to do sorting inside the array by using date

Comment: You don't have a date yet, you got a string. Parse your dictionaries (JSONs) into objects first.

Comment: @Sulthan How do I parse into objects?

Comment: @Sulthan this is my response after calling my web api using Alamofire

Comment: I vote to close this topic.  It's a poor topic showing no sign of will in tackling his own problem.

Comment: How do you have an array of that data?  With named tuples?

Comment: But he has 159 reputation so maybe its just a communication problem

Comment: What if you want to sort this data using some other criteria later on?  Are you sure you don't want to create objects lke Sulthan said... then convert the date variables within these objects to instances of DateTime... then make the objcts implement <Comparable> then you can sort them any way you want.  I will convert this comment into a real answer if you accept it! teehee!!

Comment: @BooberBunz see my edited question

Comment: yes it's the same, only longer.  Is that JSON?  JSON is not an Array.

Comment: @BooberBunz this is my response strored in mutable array

Comment: Well... I dont know what that is.  An Array to me looks like:  [Int] or [String] or [myObject]

Comment: You don't seem to be reading the comments.

Comment: @BooberBunz this is result what is got after printing my mutable array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165201/discussion-between-sachin-and-boober-bunz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert your date and time string in date object and then sort array. please check below code

```
let array = [
            [
                "city" : "Ahmedabad",
                "start_date" : "2018-12-12",
                "start_time" : "09:00:00"
            ],
            [
                "city" : "Kuching",
                "start_date" : "2018-12-13",
                "start_time" : "09:00:00"
            ]
        ]

let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
//if you want sorting using start_date and start_time
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
//else (sort only with start_date)
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let sortedArray = array.sorted { (dictionary1, dictionary2) -> Bool in
    //if you want sorting using start_date and start_time
    let date1 = dictionary1["start_date"]!+" "+dictionary1["start_time"]!
    let date2 = dictionary2["start_date"]!+" "+dictionary2["start_time"]!
    //else (sort only with start_date)
    let date1 = dictionary1["start_date"]!
    let date2 = dictionary2["start_date"]!

    let d1 = dateFormater.date(from: date1)!
    let d2 = dateFormater.date(from: date2)!
    return d1 < d2
}

print(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 solution:**

First create a Codable structure which will overlap with the JSON objects.

```
import Foundation

struct City: Codable {
    let city: String
    let start_date: Date
    let start_time: String
}
```

I have assumed the presented data was a JSON structure. So a multiline representation of that would look like so:

```
let jsonString = """
[
    {
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "start_date": "2018-12-14",
        "start_time": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "start_date": "2018-12-13",
        "start_time": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "start_date": "2018-10-05",
        "start_time": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "start_date": "2018-10-03",
        "start_time": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "start_date": "2018-10-01",
        "start_time": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "start_date": "2018-09-04",
        "start_time": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city": "Subang Jaya",
        "start_date": "2018-10-15",
        "start_time": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city": "Ahmedabad",
        "start_date": "2018-08-22",
        "start_time": "10:00:00"
    }
]
"""
```

Then to sort do this:

```
// Create a DateFormatter to conform to the dateformat in the JSON structure.

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

// Get Data from the jsonString and then setup a JSONDecoder to work with it, dont
// forget the dateDecodingStrategy.

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

// Get all the cities with their dates (and times).

let cities = try! decoder.decode([City].self, from: jsonData)

// Because the Codeable interface and the DateFormatter we can now really easy sort on the dates
// resulting in:

cities.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    return first.start_date < second.start_date
}
```

This code runs well using a playground in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution with Swift 4

First of all, you need to parse the response to your custom type. For this you should have a `struct` or `class` whatever. I'm going to use `structure`:

```
// Decodable protocol is used so that your response data can be deserialized into a Type
struct Root: Decodable {
    let city: String
    let startDate: String
    let startTime: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case city
        case startDate = "start_date"
        case startTime = "start_time"
    }
}
extension Root {
    /// converts the startDate to an actual date type which will be used for comparison
    var convertedStartDate: Date {
        return dateFormatter.date(from: startDate) ?? Date() // if server data has something in start_date that can't be converted to any date, assume that refers to current date. Or you can have your own logic here
    }
    private var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter
    }
}
```

**Sample Data:** *(Eventually, you will get this data from your response)*

```
let jsonData = """
[
{
"city" : "Ahmedabad",
"start_date" : "2018-12-14",
"start_time" : "09:00:00",
},
{
"city" : "Ahmedabad",
"start_date" : "2018-12-13",
"start_time" : "09:00:00",
},
{
"city" : "Ahmedabad",
"start_date" : "2018-10-05",
"start_time" : "09:00:00",
},
{
"city" : "Ahmedabad",
"start_date" : "2018-10-03",
"start_time" : "09:00:00",
},
{
"city" : "Ahmedabad",
"start_date" : "2018-10-01",
"start_time" : "09:00:00",
},
{
"city" : "Ahmedabad",
"start_date" : "2018-09-04",
"start_time" : "09:00:00",
},
{
"city" : "Subang Jaya",
"start_date" : "2018-10-15",
"start_time" : "09:00:00",
},
{
"city" : "Kuching",
"start_date" : "2018-08-22",
"start_time" : "10:00:00",
}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

**Then:** Deserialize your data to your custom type

```
var array = [Root]()
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: jsonData)
    array = root
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// now you can sort your data easily
let sortedArray = array.sorted { $0.convertedStartDate < $1.convertedStartDate }
print(sortedArray)
```